# How can I port a text based game on eclipse to android

Tags: java, android, porting, text-based

I am writing a text-based game in java on eclipse. It's similar to zork if you've ever played that. I wondered if there was any way to take my program and turn it into an android app easily, or if I would need to write an entirely new code for android.

Comment: That largely depends on how you've written your program. If it's well written, you'll probably just need to swap out the UI code. If not, you may very well end up having to rewrite most of it. In any case, this isn't really a question that can be sensibly answered here. Instead, grab the android sdk and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that most of your java code could be reused,
as Android uses most parts of java language.
what you would have to change is your UI representation of the program.
and to make it work with the android UI widgets.

I think that for a text-based UI game, that wont be such a hard thing to accomplish. 
although you still have to understand How android development flow works.

I don't know if there is a simple way to achieve your request.